# Problem validating data in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Is there any way that I can create a dropdown list with the IF function, like, in the A2 cell =IF(A1=0; B1:B10; 0) so if A1=0 i get a dropdown list with the B1:B10 values?. I tried to do this, but it always calls for the #VALUE! error. Thx in advance!

Searched all along in google and youtube.

Comment: Use name manager then use `INDIRECT()` function.

Comment: If I do that, it gives me a #REF! error. But if i create in another cell only the =INDIRECT(Renamedinterval) it stills give me the same error, so it's an INDIRECT function error.

Comment: Might be an error due to what you reference. I find indirect() works well when it is given good material.

Comment: Yes, I was not using "", either way, still not working with that. :(

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you can create a validation dropdown list based on a formula:

```
=IF(A1=0,CHOOSE(1;B1:B10),0)
```

When A1=0:

[image]

When A1<>0 the dropdown list won't show anything.

Comment: Not working too, CHOOSE (1; B1:B10) takes the 1st value from the interval B1:B10

Comment: Did you do the validation dropdown list? Check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-create-and-manage-drop-down-lists-28db87b6-725f-49d7-9b29-ab4bc56cefc2)